# Can't install ASP.NET4.5 in windows 8.1

Tags: asp.net, windows-8.1

I go to

> Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windowsfeatures on or
>   off

and when check ASP.NET4.5 and click Ok, give me this error:

> Windows couldn't complete the requested changes.
>
> The request is not supported.
>
> Error code: 0x80070032

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10164/fix-windows-update-errors

Comment: This link is not help